# Total per group in table format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, excel-2010

I was wondering if it is possible to create the attached table in Power BI? A sum row is needed after each *w_litres* group, to sum the *collection_litres* and to show the max *w_litres*. *% Age* in the sum row is *w_litres/collection_litres*. This is a data file and needs to be in this format. If it's not possible on Power BI, can this be done in Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used this table:

```
collection_litres  w_litres  supply_name
6104               10951     a
1833               10951     b
1246               10951     c
3771               10951     d
3996               10951     e
3699               10951     f
4988               14079     g
4537               14079     h
12979              14079     i
3887               14079     j
```

In Power BI you can create this matrix visual:

[image: matrix in Power BI]

It's not identical, but it shows the data which you need.
`collection_litres` summarized as Sum
`Max of w_litres` summarized as Maximum
`%Age` is a measure: `%Age = MAX(Table1[w_litres]) / SUM(Table1[collection_litres])`

Comment: @yasir - what do you think?